# Flight card not available in some countries?

Tags: google-schemas, google-now

I have an email markup that is triggering a boarding pass card ( with a barcode) on my phone in France, so I am sure the markup is OK.
However the very same markup received by a user in Colombia does not trigger any card. 
We tried multiple phones and they get neither the itinerary nor the boarding pass.

Can it be that flight cards are not sent to some countries ( Colombia in that example ) ?

Thank you.

Comment: I've tried testing FlightReservation with El Dorado International Airport ("iataCode": "BOG") as the arrivalAirport and was not able to trigger the a card successfully. I've also tried an airport from France - Charles de Gaulle Airport ("iataCode": "CDG") and was unsuccessful with that as well. Could you post your departure airport and arrival airport? I'll try testing your specifications and let you know my results.

Comment: I had used flight AV9544, flying from El Dorado in Bogota ( BOG ) to Rafael Nunez airport in Cartagena ( CTG ). All was fine on my phone in France but no boarding pass card on the Colombian phones . Cheers.

Comment: @Renanud, I was able to trigger a Now card with (BOG) as the arrivalAirport. Here is my result: http://i.stack.imgur.com/8F8OI.jpg So, yes, cards to trigger for Colombia.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually my issue is when BOG is the departing airport. I suspect the feature is not available in some countries, for example here Colombia, hence the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Answering to myself: indded not all countries are supported, list is here:
https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/6245953?hl=en

Colombia is not part of it at the moment.